# Bilinear form on real vector space, show that $V$ is the direct sum of the $b$-annihilator and its orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space, and $b : V \times V \to R$ a bilinear form - that is, $b(u,v)$ gives a linear transformation in each variable when the other variable is held fixed. Assume both that (1) $b$ is antisymmetric, i.e. $b(u,v) = -b(v,u)$ for all $u,v \in V$, and that (2) $b$ is non-degenerate, i.e. for every non-zero $v \in V$ there exists some $w \in V$ such that $b(v,w) \neq 0$.

For any non-empty subset $S$ in $V$ we define the $b$-annihilator of $S$, denoted $S^\perp$, by
$$S^\perp =\{v \in V : b(u,v) = 0 \text{ for all } u\in S\}.$$
a) Prove that $S^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$.

b) Let $v_1 \neq 0$ in $V$. Show that there is $w_1 \in V$ such that $b(v_1,w_1) = 1$. Prove that $\{v_1,w_1\}$ is a linearly independent set, and that if $S_1 = \text{span}\{v_1,w_1\}$, then $V$ is the direct sum of $S_1$ and $S_1^\perp$.

c) Prove that the restriction of $b$ to $S_1^\perp$ is non-degenerate.

d) Prove that the dimension of $V$ is even.

**My attempt:** I've done part a), and the easy parts of b), but I cannot figure out how to prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $S_1$ and $S_1^\perp$. I've included the work I've done, below, in case it is helpful:

a) To show that $S^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$, we need to show that if $s_1$ and $s_2$ are vectors in $S^\perp$, and $c\in R$, then $cs_1 + s_2 \in S^\perp$. But by the bilinearity of $c$, 
$$b(u,cs_1 + s_2) = b(u,cs_1) + b(u,s_2) = cb(u,s_1) + b(u,s_2),$$
for any $u \in S$, and thus $cs_1 + s_2 \in S^\perp$. Also, because $0 = 0 s$, where $s \in S^\perp$, we have $b(u,0) = 0 b(u,s) = 0$, so $0 \in S^\perp$. Thus, $S^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$, as desired.

b) First, we show that for any $v_1 \neq 0$ in $V$, there exists $w_1 \in V$ such that $b(v_1,w_1) = 1$. By the non-degenerate property of $b$, there exists some $w \in V$ such that 
$$b(v_1,w) \neq 0.$$
Let $b(v_1,w) = \alpha \in R$, and let $w_1 = \frac{1}{\alpha} w$. Now, be the bilinearity property, we have
$$b(v_1,w_1) = b\left(v_1,\frac{1}{\alpha} w\right) = \frac{1}{\alpha} b(v_1,w) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\alpha = 1,$$
so $b(v_1,w_1) = 1$, and we are done. To show that $\{v_1,w_1\}$ is linearly independent, let $c,d \in R$, and suppose that
$$\alpha v_1 + \beta w_1 = 0.$$
This implies, by the bilinearity of $b$, that 
$$b(\alpha v_1 + \beta w_1,u_1) = 0, \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ b(u_2,\alpha v_1 + \beta w_1) =0,$$
for any $u_1, u_2 \in V$. Letting $u_1 = v_1$, we have
$$\alpha b(v_1,v_1) + \beta b(w_1,v_1) = 0, \ \ \ \text{ and }$$
$$\alpha b(v_1,v_1) + \beta b(v_1,w_1) = 0.$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first tells us that
$$\beta b(w_1,v_1) - \beta b(v_1,w_1) = 0,$$
but $b$ is antisymmetric, so we have found that
$$-2\beta b(v_1,w_1) = -2\beta = 0,$$
which implies that $\beta = 0$. Now, if $\beta = 0$, then $\alpha v_1 = 0$, but $v_1 \neq 0$, and thus $\alpha = 0$. So, $v_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly independent.

**Part I need help with:** Finally, to show that $V = S_1 \oplus S_1^\perp$, first we show that $S_1 \cap S_1^\perp = \{0\}$. If $s \in S_1$, then $s = \alpha v_1 + \beta w_1$, for some $\alpha, \beta \in R$. Now, consider $t = \beta v_1 + \beta w_1$, which is in $S_1$. We have
$$b(t,s) = (\beta v_1 + \beta w_1, \alpha v_1 + \beta w_1)$$
$$= \beta \alpha(v_1,v_1) + \beta \alpha(w_1,v_1) + \beta^2 (v_1, w_1) +\beta^2 (w_1,w_1)$$
$$= -\beta + \beta^2,$$
which is only equal to $0$ when $\beta = 0$. Similarly, we can let $t = \alpha v_1 + \alpha v_2$ to show that $\alpha = 0$. So, if $s \in S_1 \cap S_1^\perp$, then $s = 0$. Now, extend $S_1$ to a basis for $V$, which we will call $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1,w_1,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-2}\}$. I would like to show here that for any $x_i$, $x_i \in S_1^\perp$, but I can't figure out a way to do so. I would really appreciate a hint in the right direction, and then I will try to solve the rest on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, $-\beta + \beta^2 = 0$ also has $\beta=1$ as a solution. And also, if you extend the basis in a random way, the $x_i$ won't be in $S_1^\perp$ : indeed, if they were, you could put $x_i' = x_i+v_1$, and then $(v_1,w_1,x'_1,\dots,x'_{n-2})$ would be another basis such that $x_i'\not\in S_1^\perp$ for all $i$.

So, hint : given $s = \alpha v_1 + \beta w_1$, then $s\in S_1^\perp$ if and only if $b(s,v_1)=b(s,w_1)=0$.

For the other direction, suppose that $x\in V$ can be written as $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1\in S_1$ and $x_2\in S_1^\perp$. Can you express $x_1$ in terms of $x$, $v_1$ and $w_1$ (using $b$ of course) ? If so, try to use this formula for a general $x$ and see that it does give you the decomposition you want.